# Neo4j 5.1.0 There is no procedure with the name `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` registered for this database instance

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to migrate to `Neo4j 5.1.0`

I downloaded APOC from https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/releases

In the Neo4j browser, I checked the version:

```
RETURN apoc.version() AS output;

"5.1.0"
```

Now, when I run my Cypher queries, I receive the following error:

```
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` registered for this database instance
```

Looks like this procedure is not the part of APOC core anymore. Is it possible to get this somewhere else for Neo4j 5.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Neo4j 5.0, `APOC` has been divided into two parts `Core` and `Extended`. The `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2` is part of the extended package. The error message means, that you are only using the core package. You should install the extended APOC package, by following the instructions from here.

[APOC Extended](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/installation/).

Comment: thanks. So right now there is no `Extended` APOC for Neo4j 5.x ?

Comment: Yeah. It is expected to come this week. https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/so-many-functions-removed-from-apoc-5-0/m-p/61535